# Can I get the requestBody (webRequest.onBeforeRequest) from a ServiceWorker context?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm trying to read the requestBody from a POST request, made in a ServiceWorker context.
All I'm getting though is a rather generic error Object instead of the actual data.

The ServiceWorker is registered by the site, i.e. https://mobile.twitter.com.

If you want to take an in-depth look, the code is FOSS: https://github.com/shadowban-eu/twitter-ninja.git

Using this code (background page):

```js
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((request) => {
  if (request.method !== 'POST') {
    return;
  }
  console.log(request.requestBody);
}, {
  urls: ['https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json']
}, [
  'requestBody'
]);
```

On that request:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/saErk.png (need 10 rep to embed images)

I get:

```js
{error: "Unknown error."}
```

I'm currently poking around with some workaround ideas like injecting my own ServiceWorker to intercept the initial fetch() made by the page (using FetchEvent).

I know about using devtools.network, often seen as workaround for getting the response body of a request. Even if it were possible to get the request body with it, it wouldn't be a viable solution for me.

Someone faced this problem in the past and has maybe solved it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You are initializing this SW from inside an extension? I'm not really into extensions myself, but do you really need to do so? I would have thought that onBeforeRequest was accessible from your background scripts without a SW. And if you are running this script from an unprivileged context, then if it crashes, it's probably because `browser` is undefined.

Comment: No, I am trying to intercept a request made by a SW registered by the site itself. I am using onBeforeRequest in the background page, yes.
I think that's why the body isn't available. Guessing the SW running on another thread or some security policy prevents the background page from reading the body.

Comment: I think this is currently being addressed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766433

Comment: Hmm, not quite. If I'm reading that correctly their event never gets fired. Mine does; just not getting the POST body.
But I'll look into the workaround. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: @r.beer, did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the exact same issue as you describe. I am using onBeforeRequest() in the background page and all requests that initiate in SWs are giving me that error instead of the request body. I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: I believe this is just a bug in Chromium. See this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=976174. I linked the Chromium issue to this SO post.